# C# - Visual Studio and Rage

Tags: c#

*Hello I'm having some problems with a callout making I don't know if anyone here can help me but I'll try asking anyway.*

**Information**
I'm making a CalloutPack for a game called Grand Theft Auto 5 while using RagePluginHook an add-on needed for that to make it work.

Basically, It works like this Main.cs go trough -> Handler.cs that register all the callouts (source code for main and handler down below). It uses LSPDFR.API.MOD and Rage, now i seem to get an Rage.ISpatial is invalid.   at Rage.Entity.DistanceTo(ISpatial spatialObject) and I don't really know where in my code I have f up.

I'm getting a *Take over Radio Tower Los Santos: Operation is not valid because the specified  Rage.ISpatial is invalid.   at Rage.Entity.DistanceTo(ISpatial spatialObject)*

do anyone know what I did wrong?

**Source code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Rage;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.API;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.Callouts;
using System.Drawing;
using Rage.Native;

namespace SpeedyPursuit.Callouts
{
    [CalloutInfo("Take over Raido Tower Los Santos", CalloutProbability.Medium)]
    public class TakeOverLS : Callout
    {
        private Ped Suspect;
        private Ped Suspect2;
        private Ped Suspect3;
        private Ped Suspect4;
        private Ped Suspect5;

        //cops Ped
        private Ped Fbisupervisor;
        private Ped FbiTeamMember1;
        private Ped FbiTeamMember2;
        private Ped FbiTeamMember3;
        private Ped FbiTeamMember4;

        private LHandle Pursuit;
        private bool PursuitCreated;

        private Vehicle vehicle1;
        private Vehicle vehicle2;

        private Vehicle vehicle1p;
        private Vehicle vehicle2p;
        private Vehicle vehicle3p;
        private Vehicle vehicle4p;

        private Vector3 spawnpV1;
        private Vector3 spawnpV2;

        private Vector3 spawnV1;
        private Vector3 spawnV2;

        private Vector3 spawnV1p;
        private Vector3 spawnV2p;
        private Vector3 spawnV3p;
        private Vector3 spawnV4p;

        //Cops Spawn
        private Vector3 FbisupervisorSpawn;
        private Vector3 FbiTeamMember1s;
        private Vector3 FbiTeamMember2s;
        private Vector3 FbiTeamMember3s;
        private Vector3 FbiTeamMember4s;

        //locationfollow
        private Vector3 followlocation;
        private float followheading;

        //Cops Blip
        private Blip FbisupervisorBlip;
        private Blip FbiTeamMember1Blip;

        private Blip SuspectBlip;
        private Blip SuspectBlip2;
        private Blip SuspectBlip3;
        private Blip SuspectBlip4;
        private Blip SuspectBlip5;

        private float heading;
        private float headingv1;
        private float headingv2;

        private float headingv1p;
        private float headingv2p;
        private float headingv3p;
        private float headingv4p;

        //cops heading
        private float headingfbisup;
        private float FbiTeamMember1heading;
        private float FbiTeamMember2heading;
        private float FbiTeamMember3heading;
        private float FbiTeamMember4heading;

        private Vector3 Spawnpoint;
        private Vector3 Spawnpoint2;
        private Vector3 Spawnpoint3;
        private Vector3 Spawnpoint4;
        private Vector3 Spawnpoint5;

        private int counter;
        private int counter2;

        public override bool OnBeforeCalloutDisplayed()
        {

            //cops spawn
            FbiTeamMember1s = new Vector3(845f, 1285f, 360f);
            FbiTeamMember2s = new Vector3(845f, 1283f, 360f);
            FbiTeamMember3s = new Vector3(847f, 1284f, 360f);
            FbiTeamMember4s = new Vector3(847f, 1286f, 360f);

            followlocation = new Vector3(801f, 1276f, 360);
            followheading = 86.647f;

            Spawnpoint = new Vector3(778f, 1287, 360f);
            Spawnpoint2 = new Vector3(779f, 1289, 360f);
            Spawnpoint3 = new Vector3(778f, 1270f, 360f);
            Spawnpoint4 = new Vector3(787f, 1266f, 360f);
            Spawnpoint5 = new Vector3(782f, 1297f, 361f);

            FbisupervisorSpawn = new Vector3(855f, 1281f, 359f);

            headingv1 = 357.922f;
            headingv2 = 51.345f;

            // cops heading
            headingfbisup = 23.187f;
            FbiTeamMember1heading = 174.126f;
            FbiTeamMember2heading = 354.127f;
            FbiTeamMember3heading = 93.946f;
            FbiTeamMember4heading = 255.905f;

            headingv1p = 119.149f;
            headingv2p = 66.722f;
            headingv3p = 320.630f;
            headingv4p = 358.971f;

            spawnV1 = new Vector3(808f, 1279f, 360f);
            spawnV2 = new Vector3(807f, 1272f, 360f);

            spawnV1p = new Vector3(855f, 1278f, 359f);
            spawnV2p = new Vector3(847f, 1276f, 359f);
            spawnV3p = new Vector3(848f, 1290f, 359f);
            spawnV4p = new Vector3(843f, 1283f, 359f);

            ShowCalloutAreaBlipBeforeAccepting(Spawnpoint, 30f);
            AddMinimumDistanceCheck(240f, Spawnpoint);
            AddMaximumDistanceCheck(4000f, Spawnpoint);
            CalloutMessage = "~r~Multiple suspects~w~ have taken over the Los Santos Radio Tower";
            CalloutPosition = Spawnpoint;
            Functions.PlayScannerAudioUsingPosition("CRIME_ASSAULT_WITH_A_DEADLY_WEAPON_01 IN_OR_AT", Spawnpoint);

            PursuitCreated = false;

            return base.OnBeforeCalloutDisplayed();
        }

        public override bool OnCalloutAccepted()
        {
            try
            {
                Game.DisplayNotification("char_call911", "char_call911", "~b~SpeedyPursuit~b~", "~r~TO ALL UNITS~w~", "~r~Dispacth:~w~ All Units responde immediately, Multiple armed suspect have forcefully taken over the radio tower in Los Santos");
                Game.DisplayNotification("~r~CODE:~w~ ~Y~3 Response~w~");
                Functions.PlayScannerAudio("UNITS_RESPOND_CODE_03_01");

                Suspect = new Ped("MP_M_BOGDANGOON", Spawnpoint, heading);
                Suspect.IsPersistent = true;
                Suspect.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                Suspect2 = new Ped("MP_M_BOGDANGOON", Spawnpoint2, heading);
                Suspect2.IsPersistent = true;
                Suspect2.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                Suspect3 = new Ped("MP_M_BOGDANGOON", Spawnpoint3, heading);
                Suspect3.IsPersistent = true;
                Suspect3.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                Suspect4 = new Ped("MP_M_BOGDANGOON", Spawnpoint4, heading);
                Suspect4.IsPersistent = true;
                Suspect4.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                Suspect5 = new Ped("MP_M_BOGDANGOON", Spawnpoint5, heading);
                Suspect5.IsPersistent = true;
                Suspect5.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                //Cops ped identifer
                Fbisupervisor = new Ped("S_M_Y_SWAT_01", FbisupervisorSpawn, headingfbisup);
                Fbisupervisor.IsPersistent = true;
                Fbisupervisor.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                FbiTeamMember1 = new Ped("S_M_Y_SWAT_01", FbiTeamMember1s, FbiTeamMember1heading);
                FbiTeamMember1.IsPersistent = true;
                FbiTeamMember1.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                FbiTeamMember2 = new Ped("S_M_Y_SWAT_01", FbiTeamMember2s, FbiTeamMember2heading);
                FbiTeamMember2.IsPersistent = true;
                FbiTeamMember2.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                FbiTeamMember3 = new Ped("S_M_Y_SWAT_01", FbiTeamMember3s, FbiTeamMember3heading);
                FbiTeamMember3.IsPersistent = true;
                FbiTeamMember3.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                FbiTeamMember4 = new Ped("S_M_Y_SWAT_01", FbiTeamMember4s, FbiTeamMember4heading);
                FbiTeamMember4.IsPersistent = true;
                FbiTeamMember4.BlockPermanentEvents = true;

                //swat blip

                FbiTeamMember1Blip = FbiTeamMember1.AttachBlip();
                FbiTeamMember1Blip.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                FbiTeamMember1Blip.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                FbisupervisorBlip = Fbisupervisor.AttachBlip();
                FbisupervisorBlip.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                FbisupervisorBlip.IsRouteEnabled = true;

                SuspectBlip = Suspect.AttachBlip();
                SuspectBlip.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                SuspectBlip.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                SuspectBlip2 = Suspect.AttachBlip();
                SuspectBlip2.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                SuspectBlip2.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                SuspectBlip3 = Suspect.AttachBlip();
                SuspectBlip3.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                SuspectBlip3.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                SuspectBlip4 = Suspect.AttachBlip();
                SuspectBlip4.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                SuspectBlip4.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                SuspectBlip5 = Suspect.AttachBlip();
                SuspectBlip5.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                SuspectBlip5.IsRouteEnabled = false;

                Suspect.CanAttackFriendlies = false;
                Suspect2.CanAttackFriendlies = false;
                Suspect3.CanAttackFriendlies = false;
                Suspect4.CanAttackFriendlies = false;
                Suspect5.CanAttackFriendlies = false;

                vehicle1 = new Vehicle("BURRITO", spawnV1, headingv1);
                vehicle2 = new Vehicle("BURRITO", spawnV2, headingv2);
                vehicle1p = new Vehicle("RIOT", spawnV1p, headingv1p);
                vehicle2p = new Vehicle("RIOT", spawnV2p, headingv2p);
                vehicle3p = new Vehicle("POLICE", spawnV3p, headingv3p);
                vehicle4p = new Vehicle("RIOT", spawnV4p, headingv4p);

                vehicle1p.IsSirenOn = true;
                vehicle1p.IsSirenSilent = true;
                vehicle2p.IsSirenOn = true;
                vehicle2p.IsSirenSilent = true;
                vehicle3p.IsSirenOn = true;
                vehicle3p.IsSirenSilent = true;
                vehicle4p.IsSirenOn = true;
                vehicle4p.IsSirenSilent = true;

                Suspect.RelationshipGroup = "ATTACKER";
                Suspect2.RelationshipGroup = "ATTACKER";
                Suspect3.RelationshipGroup = "ATTACKER";
                Suspect4.RelationshipGroup = "ATTACKER";
                Suspect5.RelationshipGroup = "ATTACKER";
                FbiTeamMember1.RelationshipGroup = "COP";
                FbiTeamMember2.RelationshipGroup = "COP";
                FbiTeamMember3.RelationshipGroup = "COP";
                FbiTeamMember4.RelationshipGroup = "COP";
                Game.LocalPlayer.Character.RelationshipGroup = "COP";
                Game.SetRelationshipBetweenRelationshipGroups("ATTACKER", "COP", Relationship.Hate);
                Game.SetRelationshipBetweenRelationshipGroups("COP", "ATTACKER", Relationship.Hate);
                Suspect.StaysInGroups = true;
                Suspect2.StaysInGroups = true;
                Suspect3.StaysInGroups = true;
                Suspect4.StaysInGroups = true;
                Suspect5.StaysInGroups = true;
                FbiTeamMember1.StaysInGroups = true;
                FbiTeamMember2.StaysInGroups = true;
                FbiTeamMember3.StaysInGroups = true;
                FbiTeamMember4.StaysInGroups = true;

                FbiTeamMember1.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 400, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(FbiTeamMember1, 1, true);

                FbiTeamMember2.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 400, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(FbiTeamMember2, 1, true);

                FbiTeamMember3.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 400, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(FbiTeamMember3, 1, true);

                FbiTeamMember4.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 400, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(FbiTeamMember4, 1, true);

                Suspect.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 400, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(Suspect, 1, true);

                Suspect2.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 310, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(Suspect2, 1, true);

                Suspect3.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 200, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(Suspect3, 1, true);

                Suspect4.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 170, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(Suspect4, 1, true);

                Suspect5.Inventory.GiveNewWeapon("WEAPON_CARBINERIFLE", 130, true);
                NativeFunction.Natives.SetPedCombatAttributes(Suspect5, 1, true);

            }
            catch
            {
                Game.LogTrivial("SpeedyPursuit - Something went wrong during loading section");
                End();
            }
            return base.OnCalloutAccepted();
          

            
        }
        public override void Process()
        {

            base.Process();


            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(Fbisupervisor) <= 5f)
            {

                Game.DisplayHelp("Speak with the SWAT Operatin Lader, To do so press ~y~Y~w~", false);
                if (Game.IsKeyDown(Handler.TalkKey))
                {

                    counter++;

                    if (counter == 1)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ Alright listen closely I will only say this once");
                    }
                    if (counter == 2)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~b~Offier:~w~ Yes sir");
                    }
                    if (counter == 3)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ Multiple suspects have forcefully taken over the Radio Station");

                    }
                    if (counter == 4)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ They are armed to the teeth with rifles and ammo that can last for days");
                    }
                    if (counter == 5)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ Negotiations have ended terriblely and our only last option is to lunch ~o~operation payback~w~");

                    }
                    if (counter == 6)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ We will force entry through the front gates with swat team ~o~BRAVO~w~");

                    }
                    if (counter == 7)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ Our priority is to either eliminate the targets or force them to surrender, Secondly find any hostages and free them");

                    }
                    if (counter == 8)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ You will lead team ~o~BRAVO~w~, when ready talk to your team and start the operation!");
                        FbiTeamMember1Blip.Flash(counter, 1);
                    }
                    if (counter == 9)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Opeator:~w~ Do you understand my commands!");

                    }
                    if (counter == 10)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~b~Offier:~w~ Yes sir!");

                    }
                    if (counter == 11)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~b~No further speech here, when ready for breach talk to your team.~w~");
                        Game.DisplayHelp("Speak with your ~o~swat team~w~", false);
                    }


                }
            }
            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(FbiTeamMember1) <= 5f)
            {

                Game.DisplayHelp("Speak with your SWAT Team, To do so press ~y~Y~w~", false);
                if (Game.IsKeyDown(Handler.TalkKey))
                {

                    counter2++;

                    if (counter2 == 1)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Member:~w~ We are ready to force entry when you are, sir!");
                    }
                    if (counter2 == 2)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~b~Offier:~w~ Great, now let's do this");
                    }
                    if (counter2 == 3)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~b~Offier:~w~ The gun men are armed and they won't be happy with our entrance");

                    }
                    if (counter2 == 4)
                    {
                        Game.DisplaySubtitle("~y~SWAT Member:~w~ Understood sir");
                        FbiTeamMember1.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                        FbiTeamMember2.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                        FbiTeamMember3.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                        FbiTeamMember4.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!PursuitCreated && Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(Suspect) <= 55f)
            {

                Pursuit = Functions.CreatePursuit();
                Functions.AddPedToPursuit(Pursuit, Suspect);
                Functions.AddPedToPursuit(Pursuit, Suspect2);
                Functions.AddPedToPursuit(Pursuit, Suspect3);
                Functions.AddPedToPursuit(Pursuit, Suspect4);
                Functions.AddPedToPursuit(Pursuit, Suspect5);
                Functions.SetPursuitIsActiveForPlayer(Pursuit, true);

                Suspect.Tasks.FightAgainstClosestHatedTarget(200);
                Suspect2.Tasks.FightAgainstClosestHatedTarget(200);
                Suspect3.Tasks.FightAgainstClosestHatedTarget(200);
                Suspect4.Tasks.FightAgainstClosestHatedTarget(200);
                Suspect5.Tasks.FightAgainstClosestHatedTarget(200);

                PursuitCreated = true;
            }

            if (PursuitCreated && !Functions.IsPursuitStillRunning(Pursuit))
            {
                End();
            }

            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(Suspect) <= 60f)
            {
                Suspect.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                Suspect2.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                Suspect3.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                Suspect4.BlockPermanentEvents = false;
                Suspect5.BlockPermanentEvents = false;

            }
            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(vehicle1p) > 310f)
            {
                vehicle1p.Delete();
            }
            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(vehicle2p) > 310f)
            {
                vehicle2p.Delete();
            }
            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(vehicle3p) > 310f)
            {
                vehicle3p.Delete();
            }
            if (Game.LocalPlayer.Character.DistanceTo(vehicle4p) > 310f)
            {
                vehicle4p.Delete();
            }
            if (Rage.Game.IsKeyDown(Handler.EndCallout))
            {
                End();
                vehicle1.Delete();
                vehicle2.Delete();
                Suspect.Delete();
                Suspect2.Delete();
                Suspect3.Delete();
                Suspect4.Delete();
                Suspect5.Delete();
                SuspectBlip.Delete();
                SuspectBlip2.Delete();
                SuspectBlip3.Delete();
                SuspectBlip4.Delete();
                SuspectBlip5.Delete();
                vehicle1p.Delete();
                vehicle2p.Delete();
                vehicle3p.Delete();
                vehicle4p.Delete();

            }

            if (!Suspect.Exists() || Game.LocalPlayer.Character.IsDead || !Suspect2.Exists() || !Suspect3.Exists() || !Suspect4.Exists() || !Suspect5.Exists())
            {
                End();

            }

        }
        

        public override void End()
        {
            base.End();

            if (SuspectBlip.Exists())
            {
                SuspectBlip.Delete();
            }
            if (SuspectBlip2.Exists())
            {
                SuspectBlip2.Delete();
            }
            if (SuspectBlip3.Exists())
            {
                SuspectBlip3.Delete();
            }
            if (SuspectBlip4.Exists())
            {
                SuspectBlip4.Delete();
            }
            if (SuspectBlip5.Exists())
            {
                SuspectBlip5.Delete();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember1Blip.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember1Blip.Delete();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember1Blip.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember1Blip.Delete();
            }
            if (FbisupervisorBlip.Exists())
            {
                FbisupervisorBlip.Delete();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember1.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember1.Dismiss();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember2.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember2.Dismiss();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember3.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember3.Dismiss();
            }
            if (FbiTeamMember4.Exists())
            {
                FbiTeamMember4.Dismiss();
            }

            Game.LogTrivial("SpeedyPursuit - TakeOverLS cleaned up!");
            Game.DisplayNotification("~b~SpeedyPursuit~w~ - ~g~Code 4~w~");
            Functions.PlayScannerAudio("ATTENTION_ALL_UNITS WE_ARE_CODE 4");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.cs**

```
using LSPD_First_Response;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Rage;
using Rage.Native;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.API;
using LSPD_First_Response.Mod.Callouts;
using LSPD_First_Response.Engine.Scripting.Entities;
using SpeedyPursuit;
using SpeedyPursuit.Callouts;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SpeedyPursuit
{
    public class Main : Plugin
    {
        
        public override void Initialize()
        {
      
            Functions.OnOnDutyStateChanged += OnOnDutyStateChangedHandler;
            Game.LogTrivial("SpeedyPursuit" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString() + " has been initialised.");
            Game.LogTrivial("Go on duty to fully load SpeedyPursuit.");
        }
       
        public override void Finally()
        {
            Game.LogTrivial("SpeedyPursuit has been cleaned up.");
        }
        
        private static void OnOnDutyStateChangedHandler(bool OnDuty)
        {
            
            if (OnDuty)
            {
                Handler.Initialize();

                Game.DisplayNotification("web_lossantospolicedept", "web_lossantospolicedept", "~b~SpeedyPursuit~b~", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString() + " has loaded ~g~successfully~w~", "~o~SpeedyPursuit~w~ Is now running                              Update name: ~o~Proud-unit~w~");
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Comment: "Take over Radio" or "Take over Raido" ?  Please explain what you are trying to do with this code. Do not let the use GUESS what you want to do with it.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, are you referring to the [RAGE Plugin Hook by MulleDK19](https://ragepluginhook.net/) or being very angry that the code is not working?

Comment: Which line?....

Comment: @AndrewMorton Correct i'm reffering to RAGE Plugin Hook, not angry need a couple of fresh eyes because I don't know where I f up.

Comment: @Stefan That i don't know, i have been staring at this for 2 hours now

Comment: The debugger should show you which line the error occures

Comment: @Stefan That’s the thing it dosen’t show any errors when building the .dll, .ini. pdb i only get the rage error

Comment: Then use your debuggers step function to see when the error occurs. You see it somewhere, you need to know what triggers it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).